# Object is not save in database, in @OneToOne relation ship using springboot restApi

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have created User Entity Class, inside that class, i have taken another class **"UserWorkDetails"** reference with **@OneToOne** relationship. while **saving** it into database only user class is saved, **but "UserWorkDetails" class object is not saved in DB.**

User ENtity Class

```
package com.springboot.revise.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userID;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "usercity")
    private String userCity;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private UserWorkDetails details;

// not added default constructor 
    public User() {
    }

    public UserWorkDetails getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(UserWorkDetails details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserCity() {
        return userCity;
    }

    public void setUserCity(String userCity) {
        this.userCity = userCity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userID=" + userID + ", userName=" + userName + ", userCity=" + userCity + "]";
    }

}
```

UserWorkDetails entity class

```
package com.springboot.revise.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
@Table(name = "work_details")
public class UserWorkDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int workIDDetail;

    @Column(name = "companyName")
    private String workCurrentCompanyName;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String workCity;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user;

    public UserWorkDetails() {
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getWorkIDDetail() {
        return workIDDetail;
    }

    public void setWorkIDDetail(int workIDDetail) {
        this.workIDDetail = workIDDetail;
    }

    public String getWorkCurrentCompanyName() {
        return workCurrentCompanyName;
    }

    public void setWorkCurrentCompanyName(String workCurrentCompanyName) {
        this.workCurrentCompanyName = workCurrentCompanyName;
    }

    public String getWorkCity() {
        return workCity;
    }

    public void setWorkCity(String workCity) {
        this.workCity = workCity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserWorkDetails [workIDDetail=" + workIDDetail + ", workCurrentCompanyName=" + workCurrentCompanyName
                + ", workCity=" + workCity + ", user=" + user + "]";
    }

}
```

Controller

```
    // adding user to database 
    @PostMapping("/user")
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return daoImpel.addUser(user);
        
    }
```

Application file

```
#data-base configuration

spring.datasource.name=spring_boot_api
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/revision_spring
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.data.rest.base-path=api/
```

UserRepository interface

```
package com.springboot.revise.userdao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.springboot.revise.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

[image: API Response]

Database tables
User Table
[image]

UserWorkDetails

[image]

Comment: Entries are present in both tables. So it is working as expected

Comment: Userid--> (foreign key) in :UserWorkDetails" class is getting null.

Comment: Got it, please read my answer to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

In `User` class please refactor `setDetails`method like this and try again.

```
public void setDetails(UserWorkDetails details) {
        this.details = details;
        details.setUser(this);
}
```